# Missing assembly reference Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory, assembly-references

I'm currently developing a Xamarin.Android application in VS2013.
I want to implement Azure Active Directory in my app following this [guide](http://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-xamarin-mobile-apps-using-azure-active-directory/). Then I add `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` nuget package as described.

Then I want to add an AuthenticationResult attribute, but then I got a missing assemble reference error. Even when I explicitely write (or drag and drop) `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult`.

I looked everywhere for solutions, but none fits my problem. (Upgrade/Downgrade target framework didn't solve the issue)
If anyone has an idea about this, I would be really thankful because I'm getting out of ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out what was the problem. I had to use a specific version of the package since it's a pre-released version. I had to install 3.0.110281957 exactly then it recognize the reference as I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Few things to check or try:

Does the Reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory appear in the References list from your solution?

If it appears, what are the properties, like copy to output, absolute/relative path?

Is it added for all Project configurations (Debug/Release)?

Comment: Yes it appears.
Absolute path is : `C:\Users\Charly\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestCharly_Xamarin\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.2.204281119-alpha\lib\net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll`
Then relative path might be `packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.2.204281119-alpha\lib\net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll`
I don't really understand what you mean with "Is it added for all project configuration ?", I'm quite new to VS. I'm obviously running un Debug configuration right now.